# D3js selectAll text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I realize this should be very easy, and i have seen a tutorial on pluralsight that i have copied. Still i cannot produce any good results. I am trying to draw text in my SVG element.

The SVG element is defind as so:

```
SVG = d3.select("#wellguideDiagram")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
        width: width + (padding * 2),
        height: height + (padding * 2)
    });
```

Then i have just to test that i can actually write a text element done this:

```
SVG.append("text").text("wrææææææææææææææææææææl").attr({
    y: function (d) { return 250; },
    x: function () { return diagramWidth + 30 + (padding * 2); },
    fill: "red",
    "font-size": "15px",
    dy: ".35em"
});
```

And i have a JSON that contains the following:

```
var limits = {
    depthdefinition: {
        elements: [
            {
                depth: 3,
                value: "oter"
            },
            {
                depth: 30,
                value: "portugeese warship"
            },
            {
                depth: 267,
                value: "Giant Squid"
            },
            {
                depth: 300,
                value: "seabed"
            }
        ]
    },
```

What i want is to be able to display all the things that are in the Json. I have tried writing this, and done countless versions of it, but the text elements simply wont appear in the svg container.

```
SVG.selectAll("text")
    .data(function () {
        alert(staticData.depthdefinition.elements);

        for (thing in staticData.depthdefinition.elements) {
            alert(thing + " " + limits.depthdefinition.elements[thing].depth +
                  " " + limits.depthdefinition.elements[thing].value);
        }
        return staticData.depthdefinition.elements;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
        alert('depth: ' + d.depth + " -> " + d.value);
        return d.depth + " -> " + d.value;
    })
    .attr({
        y: function (d) { return 250; },
        x: function () { return diagramWidth + 30 + (padding * 2); },
        fill: "red",
        "font-size": "15px",
        dy: ".34em"
    });
```

To be sure that the data function worked i put in the function call. And it works perfect. returns the values i wish for. But the text alert does not fire.

any pointers on how to make this work?

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5tIU0TRowN

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this?

Comment: Added to the post for your entertainment :)

Comment: Thanks, having a terrible time making it into a fiddle myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have `text` elements on your page already (in the axes). These are being selected when you do `.selectAll("text")` and then have the data you give to `.data()` matched to them. Hence the enter selection is empty.

To fix, you can for example use a class that's only assigned to those elements and select accordingly:

```
SVG.selectAll("text.foo")
        .data(staticData.depthdefinition.elements)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "foo")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.depth + " -> " + d.value;
        });
```

I can't seem to modify and save your JSFiddle, but the above is the salient code that you should be able to copy and paste.

On a general note, don't use `alert()` for debugging -- use `console.log()` or something like that.

Comment: I was having the same problem saving with jsfiddle, think you have to log in to save now.

Comment: It's ok... Thank you for a good solution and explanation. It works perfectly now :)

Comment: Related: Is the "text.foo" something that turns into a name that you can fetch later? Does it have to be named text, or could it be named bananas?

Comment: The latter part "foo" refers to the class of the `text` element (the dot separates element and class name). It can be anything, but should correspond to what class name you then set for the appended element.